# numpy.quantile and statistics.quantiles are calculating different. which one is true?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics, quantile

So, assume we have an array like that: 4,6,9,10,2,25,12,6,9
And then I try to calculate quantiles with numpy.quantile and statistics.quantile

```
import numpy as np
from statistics import quantiles
arr = np.array([4,6,9,10,2,25,12,6,9,])
np.quantile(arr, (0.25, 0.50, 0.75))
quantiles(arr)
```

When I calculate with numpy the result: 
`array([ 6.,  9., 10.])`

When I calculate with statistics the result: 
`[5.0, 9.0, 11.0]`

So which library is calculating correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in [`statistics.quantiles'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.quantiles) default method is “exclusive”, however the [`numpy.quantile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) is inclusive. If you write

```py
quantiles(arr, method='inclusive')
```

you get the same as numpy's answer. You should read the docs to find out which one suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, MATLAB even returns a 3rd option: [5.5    9.0   10.5]
Your question is reasonable: **How can that be?**

Let us first recall the definition of quantiles:

> In statistics and probability quantiles are cut points dividing the
>   range of a probability distribution into continuous intervals with
>   equal probabilities (...). q-quantiles are values that partition a finite set of values into q subsets of (nearly) equal sizes. 
>   From the introduction of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile).

The problem are odd-sized populations/groups. (Hereis an [example (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Examples).) You will have to choose how what to do with the fractions. The question is whether to include the point of division or not.
Apparently, `numpy` chose to include the point resulting in a round up (`ceil`) for higher quantiles and to round down (`floor`) for the lower quantiles; while `statistics` decided to not include the boundary point; and MATLAB simply provides the exact boundary -- not necessarily being a part of the set.

Now to the real question: **what is correct?** All of them.
The difference will be negligible at larger groups/populations as are typical for statistics;)